# Difference between caching & gzip for static pages

Tags: memory, cache, gzip

I have implemented all caching methods such as, memcache, diskcache, and also tried GZIP. Is there any source I can refer to which explains the difference between them.

I tried memcache it is really fast compared to (diskcache + gzip) together. Why is that so?

GZIP alone compresses my file and loads equally fast.

Plus memcache does not work together with gzip. I can really confuse here. Which should I implement to safely say my web application will load reasonably fast and improve performance of my web application for static pages?

Comment: There are just under 40 million hits when googling `profile before optimizing`. You first have to find out what prevents your webapp from loading fast and gives it poor performance, then you can look into caching to fix *that*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not "Authoritative Source", but...

- When you use cache for pages, you answer on requests with this pre-made pages: save some time on avoiding generating dynamic pages
- When you compress output, you answer on requests with compressed pages (to the time of generating page you **add** compression time): save transfer-time by transferring less data by channels

Which strategy is **clean win** is heavy situation-dependent.